# How to check the status of a spring batch job whether an instance of the job is currently under execution through spring-batch-admin?

Tags: rest, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I have a requirement where i have created a custom UI for spring-batch monitoring using the spring-batch-admin JSON api. I have a requirement where i dont want to allow the user to start job when an instance of that job is currently under progress.

Is there any REST Url which can give me a status of a job instance whether a job is in progress or not ?

Is there any way to develop a custom REST url to provide this functionality.

Kindly help.

Comment: Any option to use Spring Cloud Data Flow instead of Spring Batch Admin?

Answer (score 0):

Never used this API, but from this site: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/reference/json.html

You can get the status of the last job (so, the one running if there is one running) with `http://localhost:8080/sprin-batch-admin-sample/batch/jobs/job1.json` (replacing with job1 your actual job name and server). The parameter `lastJobExecutionStatus` should be `STARTING`, `STARTED` or `STOPPING` if it's still running.

List of possible status (check your batch version): http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/BatchStatus.html#STARTING

Note that the job might crash, leaving it in a state like `STARTED`.

EDIT: Server-side, you can create a rest endpoint and use the `SynchronizedJobLauncher` class which "synchronizes jobs globally so that only one execution of a given Job can be active at once." (http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/admin/launch/package-summary.html). There are many resources on how to create a rest endpoint for json, and how to inject a `JobLauncher`.

Other possibilities are listed here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/reference/reference.xhtml

Comment: If i want to add additional capabilites into the rest urls provided by the spring-batch-admin , how would i do so ?

Comment: You can either change your Spring configuration server side to change the json API behavior (second line in my edit) or create your own rest endpoint in Java server-side.